# JSON Formatting with Jersey, Jackson, & Google GSON using Curl Command

Tags: json, curl, jersey, jackson, gson

Using Java 6, Tomcat 7, Jersey 1.15, Jackson 2.0.6 (from FasterXml maven repo), & Google GSON 2.2.2, 
I am trying to pretty print the JSON String so it will look indented by the curl -X GET command line.

I created a simple web service which has the following architecture:

My POJOs (model classes):

Family.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Family {
    private String father;
    private String mother;

    private List<Children> children;

    // Getter & Setters
}
```

Children.java:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Children {
    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String gender;

    // Getters & Setters
}
```

Using a Utility Class, I decided to hard code the POJOs as follows:

```
public class FamilyUtil {

    public static Family getFamily() {
        Family family = new Family();
        family.setFather("Joe");
        family.setMother("Jennifer");

        Children child = new Children();
        child.setName("Jimmy");
        child.setAge("12");
        child.setGender("male");
        List<Children> children = new ArrayList<Children>();

        children.add(child);

        family.setChildren(children);
        return family;
    }
}
```

My web service:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.myapp.util.FamilyUtil;

@Path("")
public class MyWebService {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public static String getFamily() throws IOException, 
                                            JsonGenerationException, 
                                            JsonMappingException, 
                                            JSONException, 
                                            org.json.JSONException {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
            String uglyJsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(FamilyUtil.getFamily());
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
            JsonElement jsonElement = parser.parse(uglyJsonString);
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonElement));
            return gson.toJson(jsonElement);
    }
}
```

When I run this using:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/mywebservice
```

I get this in my Eclipse's console (which is exactly what I want from curl command):

```
{
  "father": "Joe",
  "mother": "Jennifer",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Jimmy",
      "age": "12",
      "gender": "male"
    }
  ]
}
```

But from the command line curl command listed above, I get this 
(there are 4 spaces after \n but JavaRanch's forum doesn't show it):

```
"{\n  \"father\": \"Joe\",\n  \"mother\": \"Jennifer\",\n  \"children\": [\n    {\n      \"name\": \"Jimmy\",\n      \"age\": \"12\",\n      \"gender\": \"male\"\n    }\n  ]\n}"
```

How can I make the JSON formatting to be identical to what I am getting in Eclipse's console by using the curl command?

Thanks for taking the time to read this...

Comment: The newline character is basically a shell directive. Curl is not a shell, it displays the data exactly as retrieved from the HTTP response. On a side note, this seems like an incredible amount of trouble you are going to for no practical purpose. You can use an online tool like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to format your JSON nicer if you want to be able to analyze/debug it.

Comment: You shouldn't be pretty printing from a web server. First, `\n` isn't recognized in HTML as a newline. Second ... you shouldn't be pretty printing from a web server. That's the client's job.